# Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT]: Connecting timed out [5000ms]

Tags: flutter, dart

while calling in API is giving error
Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.CONNECT_TIMEOUT]: Connecting timed out [5000ms]

Comment: add your code with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the exception using try catch

```
try{
} on DioError catch(e){
}
```